# Authentication Popup Close Icon and Background in Porto Theme

Tags: porto-theme, icon, authentication

I am using Porto Theme (Magento 2.3.3) and I disabled guest check out. When the user clicks the "Proceed to Checkout" button, authentication popup opens but it has no background and there is a square instead of the close icon. So the text cannot be read.

I tried deploying static content but no change. Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: for a icon goto line 30 of _popups.less  `.lib-popup-button-close-icon`
should be

`._lib-popup-button-close-icon`

Comment: Tried for both _popups.less files under vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\web\css\source and vendor\magento\theme-frontend-black\web\css\source but no change @MohitPatel